# Host image and use URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My users should be able to upload their logo in my react APP,

Ideally what I want to do is upload the file somewhere IE host it and in the process of doing so, retrieve the URL for it so I can store that URL in the database along with the other settings!

My code for the user to drop the image is quite simple:

```
this.state = {  
 files: []
};

<DropZone
    onDrop={(files, acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
        this.setState({files: [...this.state.files, ...acceptedFiles]});
    }}>
    {uploadedFiles}
    {fileUpload}
</DropZone>
```

Then when saving settings i want to call a function which as I said, Uploads the image somewhere and returns that URL so i can then use it to store in a DB.

```
saveDetails = () => {
    // some code here that takes the this.state.files[0]
    uploads it somewhere then returns the URL.. THEN i call a DB storage function storing that URL to then be accessed elsewhere?!
}
```

Is there a common, easy way to do this?

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use axios to post the image data. Use FileReader to read file. Read it as a base 64 image and send it to the server. To read file as a base 64:-

```
handleDrop(acceptedFiles){
        const {onError,onChangeAvatar} = this.props;

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onabort = ()=>onError("Profile picture reading is aborted!");
        reader.onerror = ()=>onError("Error with uploaded file. Try again.");

        reader.readAsDataURL(acceptedFiles[0]);

        reader.onload = ()=>{
            const base64Image = reader.result;

            onChangeAvatar(base64Image);


        };
    }
```

Now you can use axios to post image:-

```
onChangeAvatar (base64Image){
Axios.post("/url/to?upload",base64Image).then(response=>console.log(response))
}
```

save the file and return saved url from server side.